# sqlalchemy simple example of `sum`, `average`, `min`, `max`

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

For *sqlalchemy*, Who can gently give simple examples of `SQL` functions like `sum`, `average`, `min`, `max`, for a column (`score` in the following as an example).

As for this mapper:

```
class Score(Base):
    #...
    name = Column(String)
    score= Column(Integer)
    #...
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

See [SQL Expression Language Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html) for the usage. The code below shows the usage:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
qry = session.query(func.max(Score.score).label("max_score"), 
                    func.sum(Score.score).label("total_score"),
                    )
qry = qry.group_by(Score.name)
for _res in qry.all():
    print _res
```

Comment: Does this, unlike SQL, correctly handle summing the empty set, i.e. returning `0` instead of `NULL`?

Comment: It uses respective `SQL` functions with all their pluses and minuses.

Comment: That's a pity. Something like [this](https://gist.github.com/rightfold/34ae11a759900737ed67) should work.

Comment: Link is broken.  Latest:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html

Comment: Some good examples from the SQLAlchemy docs showing how to get more control over generating the SQL:  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#counting

Answer (score 5):

From [SQLAlchemy docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html?highlight=sum#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.sum), for `sum` method, we need to use `functions.sum()`. As we can see:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import functions

result = session.query(
    functions.sum(Model.value_a + Model.value_b)
).scalar()
```

that will produce a sql like:

```sql
SELECT sum(public.model.value_a + public.model.value_b) AS sum_1 ...
```

Comment: This isn't wrong, but it's more idiomatic to use `func`, like `session.query(func.sum(Model.attr))`.